How to disable (make an error) on ChildContent?
Consider this markup:
<MyComponent>
  This is ChildContent
</MyComponent>

It is all fine if MyComponent actually supports ChildContent, if not by default user/dev will be notified about this fact in runtime.
How to disable it, so it will become compile error?
Update, Github issue for this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/57391

Reasonable question, but you should probably pose it on the AspNetCore GitHub site rather than here.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis Ok, however all the time I have responses like "use community forums like SO" :-).

That's true for most questions, but this is functionality in the Razor compiler that doesn't exist.  Post a link to an example.

To enforce that child content is not allowed at compile-time in a Blazor component, you can use the EditorRequired attribute on a required parameter. However, Blazor does not provide a built-in mechanism to prevent ChildContent at compile-time directly.
Instead, you can leverage the absence of a ChildContent parameter in your component's definition to indirectly achieve this. If a component does not define a ChildContent parameter, attempting to use it will result in a compile-time error.
Here's how you can design a component that does not support ChildContent: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
